# trendline in tradingview with a text in it (pinescript)

Tags: text, line, pine-script

In tradingview, we can draw a trendline and put text on it, set a template, etc...
is it possible with the pine script to draw a line and assign either a template or a text to the line ? or do we need to add the text in the label absolutely[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzn9z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Please read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html) for more information.

Here is an example of pivot points:

```
//@version=4
study("Pivot Points Standard", overlay=true)
higherTF = input("D", type=input.resolution)
prevCloseHTF = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, close[1], lookahead=true)
prevOpenHTF = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, open[1], lookahead=true)
prevHighHTF = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, high[1], lookahead=true)
prevLowHTF = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, low[1], lookahead=true)

pLevel = (prevHighHTF + prevLowHTF + prevCloseHTF) / 3
r1Level = pLevel * 2 - prevLowHTF
s1Level = pLevel * 2 - prevHighHTF

var line r1Line = na
var line pLine = na
var line s1Line = na

if pLevel[1] != pLevel
    line.set_x2(r1Line, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(pLine, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(s1Line, bar_index)
    line.set_extend(r1Line, extend.none)
    line.set_extend(pLine, extend.none)
    line.set_extend(s1Line, extend.none)
    r1Line := line.new(bar_index, r1Level, bar_index, r1Level, extend=extend.right)
    pLine := line.new(bar_index, pLevel, bar_index, pLevel, width=3, extend=extend.right)
    s1Line := line.new(bar_index, s1Level, bar_index, s1Level, extend=extend.right)
    label.new(bar_index, r1Level, "R1", style=label.style_none)
    label.new(bar_index, pLevel, "P", style=label.style_none)
    label.new(bar_index, s1Level, "S1", style=label.style_none)

if not na(pLine) and line.get_x2(pLine) != bar_index
    line.set_x2(r1Line, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(pLine, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(s1Line, bar_index)
```

[image]

Comment: this is a good alternative, but I want to avoid drawing another label on my chart to put the text on it, I wanted to add the text to the line itself but on the code I can't find that maybe in V6 in the future